# Facebook ARStudio: How can I set an object position?

Tags: javascript, facebook, augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

I started experimenting the ARStudio from Facebook but I couldn't figure out how can I set the position of the object from a script.
I tried something like down below but seems like `object.transform.x(or y, z)` takes "ScalarSignal" instead of numeric value. How do I set the positions of objects in ARStudio?

```
class Vector3{
    constructor(xPos = 0, yPos = 0, zPos = 0){
        var x = xPos;
        var y = yPos;
        var z = zPos;
    }
}

const FaceTracking = require("FaceTracking");
const Diagnostics = require("Diagnostics");
const Scene = require("Scene");

var sphere = Scene.root.child("sphere");
var spherePosition = new Vector3()

var mouthCenter = FaceTracking.face(0).mouth.center;
var mouthCenterPosition = new Vector3();

mouthCenter.x.monitor().subscribe(function(e){
    if(e.newValue){
        mouthCenterPosition.x = mouthCenter.x.lastValue;
    }
});

mouthCenter.y.monitor().subscribe(function(e){
    if(e.newValue){
        mouthCenterPosition.y = mouthCenter.y.lastValue;
    }
});

mouthCenter.z.monitor().subscribe(function(e){
    if(e.newValue){
        mouthCenterPosition.z = mouthCenter.z.lastValue;
    }
    // Diagnostics.log(mouthCenterPosition);
    SetSpherePosition(mouthCenterPosition);
});

function SetSpherePosition(pos){
    //This part is causing error...
    sphere.transform.x = pos.x;
    sphere.transform.y = pos.y;
    sphere.transform.z = pos.z;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ar-studio/reference/reactive_module/transformsignal_class

Additionally, try something like

```
sphere.transform.position = mouthCenterPosition;
```

The sphere object I think is likely to contain this transform module, which then has a position property you can modify. I believe setting an equal like this is how to "bind" in React. I'm new to React, any other help on this answer would be appreciated by me as well!

Answer (score 0):

If you need just apply the sphere to the mouth center you can use

sphere.transform.x = face.cameraTransform.applyToPoint(mouth.center).x;
sphere.transform.y = face.cameraTransform.applyToPoint(mouth.center).y;